# Oracle SQL left join with null values copied

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I'm not sure how to ask this question in a way that Google will understand. I want to left join two tables and have the blank fields filled in. Here's what I'm working with:

```
tbl1
| user | date  | usage |
| us1  | 01/12 |  503  |
| us1  | 02/12 |  245  |
| us1  | 03/12 |  465  |
| us2  | 02/12 |  327  |
| us2  | 03/12 |  204  |
| us3  | 02/12 |  156  |

tbl2
| dates | avg_use |
| 01/12 |   345   |
| 02/12 |   426   |
| 03/12 |   502   |

Desired output
| user | date  | usage  |  pct_of_avg  |
| us1  | 01/12 |  503   |     1.45     |
| us1  | 02/12 |  245   |     .58      |
| us1  | 03/12 |  465   |     .93      |
| us2  | 01/12 | (null) |      0       |
| us2  | 02/12 |  327   |     .95      |
| us2  | 03/12 |  204   |     .41      |
| us3  | 01/12 | (null) |      0       |
| us3  | 02/12 |  156   |     .37      |
| us3  | 03/12 | (null) |      0       |
```

I understand JOINs pretty well, so I'm aware that a typical JOIN will not be able to do this since the data in tbl1.user won't exist. Is there a way to do this in SQL at all? Bonus points for giving what I'm trying to do a name, because it would help a lot just to know how to Google this :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT U.user, T2.dates date, T1.usage, T1.usage/T2.avg_use pct_of_avg  
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT user FROM tbl1) U
CROSS JOIN tbl2 T2
LEFT JOIN tbl1 T1
    ON T2.date = T1.date  AND U.user = T1.user
```

Comment: This won't provide the desire output, as it will not have rows for dates that the user has no data for. The purpose of this question was to get a row for every date and every user.

Comment: @monitorjbl Really?, did you try it?, I'm pretty sure that my answer does take into account that every user has every date on the result, that's what the `CROSS JOIN` is doing

Comment: You edited your response. Your first query did not, but this one does. Thanks, it's exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

If your Oracle version 10g or higher you can use [partition by](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14223/analysis.htm#sthref1836) extension of `outer join` to fill in gaps in data. You will need less code. It'll be simpler, faster.

```
SQL> select t.user1
  2       , to_char(t1.dates, 'mm/yy') as date1
  3       , t.usage1
  4       , round((nvl(t.usage1, 0)/t1.avg_use), 2)  as pct_of_avg
  5   from tbl1 t
  6   partition by(t.user1)
  7   right join tbl2 t1
  8      on (t.date1 = t1.dates)
  9  ;

USER1 DATE1     USAGE1 PCT_OF_AVG
----- ----- ---------- ----------
us1   01/12        503       1.46
us1   02/12        245       0.58
us1   03/12        465       0.93
us2   01/12                     0
us2   02/12        327       0.77
us2   03/12        204       0.41
us3   01/12                     0
us3   02/12        156       0.37
us3   03/12                     0

9 rows selected
```